# Python dictionary in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I've an ajax call in my html of a django application. How can I handle the returned object in javaScript if my python backend returns a list that includes python dictionary:

html:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/api/check_variable/?name='+$("#foo").val()+'&stat='+stat_id,
        data: "check",
        success: function(response){
            alert("response[2]);
        } 
)}
```

urls.py:

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path("check_variable/", views.api_for_class_checking, name="check_variable"),
    ]
```

views.py:

```
    def api_for_class_checking(request, **kwargs):
        
        return ['id1', 'id2',{'filabel': 'label F', 'svlabel': 'labelS', 'enlabel': 'labelEn'}]
```

In this case my html page alerts just Object as response[2]. How can I get the attributes of the returned object, like the value of 'filabel' e.g. ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong to your code because your **ajax call** returned an **object**:

`{'filabel': 'label F', 'svlabel': 'labelS', 'enlabel': 'labelEn'}`

If you want to **alert** an **attribute** of your *returned data*(for example: `filabel`) you can try this in your **ajax call**:

```
alert(`${response[2].filabel}`);
```

Or,

```
alert(`${response[2]["filabel"]}`);
```

Comment: I tried both of your answers but they didn't work.

Comment: @Jaana I have edited my answer, try this time, I hope it works